# Xposed doesn't find a class to hook

Tags: java, android, xposed

I'm trying to develop mi own Xposed module for the telegram app, but when I try to hook the method called "setOnClickListener" Xposed show the following error:

> de.robv.android.xposed.XposedHelpers$ClassNotFoundError:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:Invalid name: org.telegram.ui.ProfileActivity

My code looks like:

```
findAndHookMethod("org.telegram.ui.ProfileActivity", lpparam.classLoader, "setOnClickListener", new XC_MethodHook() {
        /*@Override
        protected void beforeHookedMethod(XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            /*Functionality of the method will be there*/

        }
```

anyone knows where is the method that I want to hook?

Answer (score 2):

The method you are trying to hook is ambiguous as there are two SetOnClickListner method present in your class. So you cannot hook it directly as it will cause ambiguity errors. 
I think you are trying to modify one of avatarImage.setOnClickListener() or  writeButton.setOnClickListener() methods.

So you have to hook the method in which  avatarImage.setOnClickListener() or  writeButton.setOnClickListener() resides. Looking into the source code of org.telegram.ui.ProfileActivity Class, I think you have to hook createView(Context context) method from that class and perform the necessary modifications that you need to implement.

```
@Override
public View createView(Context context) {...}
```